# javascript to change innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change content of div "act" using nextSibling of another div.
But result is - undefined.

```
function inner(){
var abc = document.getElementById("start").nextSibling;
document.getElementById("act").innerHTML = abc.innerHTML;
 }

<img id="btnRight" src="img/btnRight.png" onclick="inner()">
<div id="act"><img src="img/home01.jpg"></div>

<div id="store">
<div id="start">
<img src="img/img01.jpg">
</div>

<div>
<img src="img/img02.jpg"> //wanted to place into "act"
</div>

<div id="end">
<img src="img/img03.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this behaviour is white space between div with id "start" and the following div. So, nextSibling will be text content. You need to do nextSibling twice:

```
var abc = document.getElementById("start").nextSibling.nextSibling;
```

Another option is to remove whitespace characters between two divs.

Comment: @ Riateche I removed white space (return character) between divs, but the result is still - undefined

Comment: There was at least two return characters between divs. Without white space it must look like `... </div><div> ...`.

Comment: Just FYI... This answer is very situational and isn't the best one that was provided.  Musa has given an answer that will always work regardless of how your HTML happens to be formatted...

Answer (score 5):

Use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling), [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nextSibling) could be a text node

```
function inner(){
    var abc = document.getElementById("start").nextElementSibling;
    document.getElementById("act").innerHTML = abc.innerHTML;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jLwyJ/)

---

If you target browser doesn't support `nextElementSibling` you can traverse the siblings and find the first element node.

```
function nextElementSibling(element) {
    while (element.nextSibling){
        element = element.nextSibling;
        if (element.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            return element;
        }
    }
    return undefined;                
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jLwyJ/1/)

Comment: Keep in mind, this is only available in Internet Explorer 9+.

Comment: Thanks, Bill, I have firefox 14

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure to skip over whitespace when traversing nodes.

```
function next(elem) {
    do {
        elem = elem.nextSibling;
    } while (elem && elem.nodeType != 1);
    return elem;                
}

function inner(){
    var abc = next(document.getElementById("start"));
    document.getElementById("act").innerHTML = abc.innerHTML;
}
```

You can see a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/CkCR3/.

Answer (score 1):

there are two way

first fix the code

```
nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML
```

or fix the html : remove all \n char

```
<img id="btnRight" src="img/btnRight.png" onclick="inner()"><div id="act"><img src="img/home01.jpg"></div><div id="store"><div id="start"><img src="img/img01.jpg"></div><div><img src="img/img02.jpg"> //wanted to place into "act"</div><div id="end"><img src="img/img03.jpg"></div></div>​
```

because div tag's next sibling is empty textNode (it can't see)

Answer (score 1):

Please change your line of code as per below;
because every next element is check for exists or not ,then get inner html.

function inner() {

```
    var abc = document.getElementById("start");
    do {
        abc = abc.nextSibling;
    } while (abc && abc.nodeType != 1);
    document.getElementById("act").innerHTML = abc.innerHTML;     
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a jsfiddle to demonstrate an easier way.
You'll notice that the act div is red and that the start div is blue. The innerHTML will change when you click the button. Also, a reason that you might see undefined is because the DOM didn't load and so it doesn't have any idea that the divs exist. Next time you should use `window.onload = inner();` to make the function run after the DOM has loaded.

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yY9Ag/16/

Comment: @ llan, thanks for your effort and explanation. I must study now each anwer line by line. So many new informations...

Comment: alice, the last few lines in javascript are only to add an onClick event handler, which you can do with inline javascript, from what you know already, most of that stuff is the same. If you have any questions, just comment back...I'd be happy to explain. :)